# Are there any advantages and disadvantages with what type of model of homomorphic computation is used?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I am curious about the advantage or disadvantage in using the different models of homomorphic computation (boolean circuits, modular arithmetic, approximate number arithmetic). Are there any specific properties of these models that make them fundamentally different in certain aspects compared with the others?

Comment: There have been votes cast to close this question as "too broad", and I can see why. I've tried to make the question slightly more specific, but IMHO is it pretty close to the edge if not over it. Listing all the properties of these models and then comparing them is probably more close to a paper than an answer on crypto.SE...